# Implementing a bucket-like method in Android

Tags: java, android

I created an application for drawing in Android.
I want to have a tool similar to Microsoft Paint's bucket tool - the tool will fill the closed area with the chosen color. So on click, I wrote:

```
boolean[][] didVisit = new boolean[getWidth()][getHeight()];
                visit ((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY(), didVisit, mBitmap.getPixel((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY()));
```

And the visit method is:

```
private void visit (int x, int y, boolean[][] didVisit, int color)
        {
            if ( x < 0 || x >= didVisit.length || y < 0 || y >= didVisit[0].length  )
            {
                return;
            }
            if (  mBitmap.getPixel(x,y) != color )
                return;
            if ( didVisit[x][y] )
                return;
            didVisit[x][y] = true;
            mBitmap.setPixel(x, y, p.getColor());
            visit(x-1,y,didVisit,color);
            visit(x,y+1,didVisit,color);
            visit(x+1,y,didVisit,color);
            visit(x,y-1,didVisit,color);
        }
```

However, this causes the application to crush (force close). I'm pretty much perplexed. I reviewed it dozens of times, and still could not see what caused the force close.

I would be glad for any kind of help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to provide the StackTrace...

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm sorry, I'm quite new at this. What do you mean by that?

Comment: If you're using Eclipse, open DDMS perspective and you'll see LogCat and Devices tabs there. Choose your device in the Device tab and logcat output will appear. Add lines with stack trace to this post.

Comment: Well, if I am doing it right, I get 04-23 18:16:25.648: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338): java.lang.StackOverflowError , then 04-23 18:16:25.648: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.getPixel(Bitmap.java:740)
04-23 18:16:25.648: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338):     at com.my.drawing.Drawing$MyView.visit(Drawing.java:208)
04-23 18:16:25.648: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338):     at com.my.drawing.Drawing$MyView.visit(Drawing.java:214)
 and then many more lines like the last one (with numbers 214-217 - the lines with visit(x-1...)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your app crashes because of stack overflow. Even for 30x30 image this algorithm makes a recursive call with depth 900! I'm not sure how big Android's stack size is, but I'm pretty sure that you should redesign your algorithm to avoid recursion.

**UPDATE**: According to your comment all I wrote is true. This algorithm will not work.

Comment: I see. It's weird because it doesn't paint even relativetly small areas. Do you have any idea on how to implement it, then?